# Why I cant generate big XLS ( > 1000 rows )?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, xls

I searched for faster XLS generation and I found this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel).

I created 10000 of products and added more fields into the model.

In XLS template I output more than 20 fields.

1000 products were exported, but when I try to increase this number ( to test performance ) LibreOffice fail to open it. Also tried to upload it to GoogleDrive and open - also fails.

Maybe something is wrong in my template ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table>
       <Row>
         <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
          ...20 headers...
       </Row>   
      <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <Row>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= product.id %></Data></Cell>
          ...20 fields ...  
        </Row>
      <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```